# JS finding the IndexOf() a substring within a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React to build a restaurant violation app, and I'm trying to return results where the searched term is a substring of the data set. However, I'm getting an error message saying;

> ViolationsRequest.jsx:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null.

Based on my tests, it looks like door.restaurant is being console-logged as undefined.  Strangely enough, this code works as an exact match, i.e., if you switch out the if block as:

```
if (this.props.restaurant == door.restaurant) {
```

This is my code block.

```
const violationElements = this.state.doors.map((door, idx) => {
      if (door.restaurant.indexOf(this.props.restaurant) !== -1) {
        console.log();
        return (
          <ViolationsView key={idx}
                      restaurant={door.restaurant}
                      building={door.building}
                      street={door.street}
                      zip={door.zip}
                      phone={door.phone}
                      cuisine={door.cuisine}
                      inspectionDate={door.inspectionDate}
                      action={door.action}
                      violationCode={door.violationCode}
                      violationDescription={door.violationDescription}
                      criticalFlag={door.criticalFlag}
                      score={door.score}
                      grade={door.grade}
                      gradeDate={door.gradeDate}
                      inspectionType={door.inspectionType}
          />
        )
      }
    });
```

This is my state.doors array:

```
  const cleanData = restaurantData.data.map((inspectionData) => {
    const [sid, id, position, createdAt, createdMeta,
      updatedAt, updatedMeta, meta, camis, dba, boro,
      building, street, zipcode, phone, cuisine,
      inspectionDate, action, violationCode,
      violationDescription, criticalFlag, score, grade,
      gradeDate, recordDate, inspectionType] = inspectionData;
    return {
      sid: sid,
      restaurant: dba,
      building: building,
      street: street,
      zip: zipcode,
      phone: phone,
      cuisine: cuisine,
      inspectionDate: inspectionDate,
      action: action,
      violationCode: violationCode,
      violationDescription: violationDescription,
      criticalFlag: criticalFlag,
      score: score,
      grade: grade,
      gradeDate: gradeDate,
      inspectionType: inspectionType,
    };
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide what the state.doors array looks like? including the door object properties and values. your `if (this.props.restaurant !== door.restaurant) ` works because its not trying to access a property on door.restaurant when its undefined which doesn't work

Comment: Unrelated have you thought about using the JSX spread operator, it would make this much easier to read as your JSX would become; <ViolationsView {...door} />

Comment: *"strangely enough, this code works as an exact match"* well, accessing an undefined property is not an issue. Trying to access a property on `undefined` is. There is a big difference between `foo.bar` and `foo.bar.baz`. *"it looks like door.restaurant is being console-logged as undefined"* Yep, that's why the error says as well. Seems like you know what the issue is. What do you want from us?

Comment: `console.log(door.restaurant, this.props.restaurant);` willing to be they are both undefined

Comment: Well that just means that `this.props.restaurant` is `undefined` or `null` as well

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT!  Some of the values in door.restaurant were coming in as null, making it difficult to find the indexOf that value.  THANK YOU EVERYONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your doors.restaurant is null, which is what the error message states. Null, not undefined. If it was undefined the error message would have said so. When you call doors.restaurant.indexOf on this value it returns an error.

As I type this, you seem to have already figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you aren't using the === operator, so with the == you are validating only value not type.
Example:

```js
var foo = null;
var bar = '';
var baz = 0;
var off = {};

console.log(bar == baz); // true
console.log(bar === baz); // false
console.log(foo == off.bar); // true
console.log(foo === off.bar); // false
```

so probably `this.props.restaurant == door.restaurant` is true
but `this.props.restaurant === door.restaurant` is false